# Overriding the @angular/pwa ngsw-worker.js

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I'm working on [an app](https://github.com/dhappy/tracker/tree/angular-8) and I would like to integrate with Firebase Messaging. To do so I need to append some code to the `ngsw-worker.js` generated by `@angular/pwa` when I build.

I tried creating a `ngsw-worker.js` in `src/`, but after running `rm -rf dist/ && ng build --prod`, the version in `dist/` didn't have my changes.

Comment: What do you mean by `I tried creating a ngsw-worker.js in src/` ?

Comment: In the `src/` directory I created the file `ngsw-worker.js` hoping it would replace the version generated by `@angular/pwa`, but it was overwritten when building.

Answer (score 1):

When the service worker module is imported into `app.module.ts`, it includes the path of the worker.

```
ServiceWorkerModule.register(
  '/ngsw-worker.js',
  { enabled: environment.production }
)
```

Change that path to something else, then in that file `importScripts('/ngsw-worker.js)`. Also include it in the `assets` section of `angular.json` so it will get copied to production.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

First you need to run

```
ng build --prod
```

So you can copy the file `ngsw-worker.js` from dist folder in the root of your project (same level with package.json) From here you can modify that file with the content you want.

Next create a file name replace-sw.sh and paste this content into that file

```
#!/bin/bash
cp ./ngsw-worker.js ./dist/
```

Finally update your package.json

```
"build": "ng build --prod && replace-sw.sh"
```

Then you can simply run `npm run build`